# DeprecationWarning in Python 3.6 and 3.7 (with Pillow, distutils, imp)

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, travis-ci, distutils

Please look at this issue:

[DeprecationWarning in Python 3.6 and 3.7](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3547)

```
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 57, in <module>
    import distutils.version
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 33, in <module>
    DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
The command "python -W error::DeprecationWarning manage.py test" exited with 1.
```

The people who commented there said it's an issue with `virtualenv`, which is fixed in `virtualenv` 16.3.0 (see the comments).

I tried to upgrade to the latest `virtualenv` (`virtualenv==16.4.3`) in the tests but the tests still fail in Python 3.6 and 3.7 with the `DeprecationWarning` when run with deprecation warnings enabled:

- `python -W error::DeprecationWarning manage.py test` [with Pillow==5.4.1](https://travis-ci.org/speedy-net/speedy-net/builds/514284524)
- `python -W error::DeprecationWarning manage.py test` [with Pillow==6.0.0](https://travis-ci.org/speedy-net/speedy-net/builds/514595887)

What is the problem?

You can see the code in the relevant branches in [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net).

For example, the branch [`uri_run_tests_with_deprecation_warnings_2019-04-02_a`](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/tree/uri_run_tests_with_deprecation_warnings_2019-04-02_a).

**Update**: I understand that the problem is that the virtual environment is activated before the `virtualenv` upgrade. So the version activated is not the same as the version after the upgrade. Is it possible to run tests on Travis with the latest `virtualenv` release, or do I have to wait until Travis upgrades it?

I created a new issue for setuptools: [github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1933](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1933)

Comment: I submitted a PR to travis-cookbooks: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/pull/1065

Answer (score 3):

## The cause: virtual environments created with outdated virtualenv

`virtualenv` embeds its own `distutils`.

Before `virtualenv==16.3.0`, the embedded `distutils` imported the deprecated `imp` module.

Travis uses cached Python virtual environments, each with updated **in-virtual-env** versions of:

- currently `virtualenv==16.6.0` for Python 3.6, and
- currently `virtualenv==16.7.8` for Python 3.7.

However, the virtual environments were created by Travis cookbooks with `virtualenv==15.1.0`.

## The fix: recreate virtual environments (with updated virtualenv)

In the case of Travis CI, in **cookbooks/travis_build_environment/recipes/virtualenv.rb**:

```
- execute 'pip install virtualenv==15.1.0'
+ execute 'pip install virtualenv==16.3.0'
```

I have submitted a PR for the fix at [travis-ci/travis-cookbooks#1065](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/pull/1065).

## The workaround: reinstall distutils (with updated virtualenv)

This may be sufficient for those who don't want to (or can't) recreate their virtual environments.

After deep-diving into the source code of Travis CI and virtualenv, I found that you can actually install `distutils` inside a virtual environment with the updated **in-virtual-env** version of `virtualenv`:

```
before_script:
  - python -c 'import os, virtualenv; virtualenv.install_distutils(os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"])'
```

MCVE of **travis.yml**:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.5"
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
os: linux
dist: bionic
install: skip
before_script:
  - python -c 'import os, virtualenv; virtualenv.install_distutils(os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"])'
script:
  - python -W error::DeprecationWarning -c 'import distutils'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I prefer to see if Travis CI will fix it, before I change `.travis.yml` in our project. I prefer not to change `.travis.yml` in our project.

Comment: Agreed, Travis CI should fix it since they're causing it for everyone.